# Split RDD[String] to RDD[tuples]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd

I'm a beginner on Scala and RDD. I'm using Scala on Spark 2.4. I have a RDD[String] with lines like that:

```
(a, b, c, d, ...)
```

I would like to split this String at each coma to get an `RDD[(String, String, String, ...)]`.

Solutions like the following are obviously not possible regarding the number of elements.

```
rdd.map(x => (x.split(",")(0), x.split(",")(1), x.split(",")(2)))
```

May be is there a way to automate that? Everything working would be fine.

Despite my efforts, I have no solution to my issue so far,

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tuples have fixed size, do you know how many elements would contain your string?

Comment: Hum not really, but I can probably find a way to count the number of commas. Assuming that I know my tuples size, what would be the solution ?

Comment: I mean you'd have to know the size of a tuple at compile time. If a number of elements may vary, then you can't really use tuples, you'd have to stay with `Array`.

Comment: Oh ok, so the number of elements is fixed in my case

Comment: What if a line has an incorrect number of columns? Wouldn't it be simpler to map into an `RDD[Seq[String]] `?

Comment: The final goal is to convert my RDD to a DataFrame using the method toDF() which take a RDD of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the maximum tuple size is limited to 22, so it won't be so long to list them all ...

By the way, in the book *Spark in Action*, on page *110*, it wrotes:

> There's no elegant way to convert an array to a tuple, so you have to resort to this ugly expression:

```
scala> val itPostsRDD = itPostsSplit.map(x => (x(0), x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), x(7), x(8), x(9), x(10), x(11), x(12))
itPostsRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If the number of elements is fixed, you can do something like:

```
val tuples =
  rdd
    .map(line => line.replaceAll("[\\(\\)]", "").split(","))
    .collect {
      case Array(col1, col2, ..., coln) => (col1, col2, ..., coln)
    }
// tuples: RDD[(String, String, ..., String)]
```

Comment: This solution should work but I have something like 200+ Tuples :/

Comment: Then, it would be better to either just do the split and create a `DataFrame` of one **Column** _(an array)_, and using **explode** to create new columns from it. Or read the file as a `DataFrame` of lines _(using text)_, and using regex or something explode it. I think you should try that way and if you have problems, create a new question providing more details.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to just write the mapping function:

```
def parse(s: String) = s.split(",") match {
    case Array(a,b,c) => (a,b,c)
}

parse("x,x,x") // (x,x,x)
```

You could write the more generic solution using shapeless:

```
def toTuple[H <: HList](s: String)(implicit ft: FromTraversable[H], t: Tupler[H]) = s.split(",").toHList[H].get.tupled
```

then you can use it directly:

```
toTuple[String :: String :: String :: HNil]("x,x,x") // (x,x,x)
toTuple[String :: String :: HNil]("x,x") // (x,x)
```

or fix then type and then use it:

```
def parse3(s: String) = toTuple[String :: String :: String :: HNil](s)

parse3("x,x,x") // (x,x,x)
```